# How to cause a "back button' from a java servlet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I have a form on page A. It submits some data to a java servlet on servlet B. Servlet B does some error checking. If that checking shows errors I'd like to send the user back to page A via a back button type action (which keeps the data in the form). Is there a way to do this in a Java servlet response? In case it matters, this is in Google AppEngine's Java platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. What you can do though, is send back the HTML markup of the page containing the form, and prepopulate the form with the values submitted by the user:

```
<input type="text" value="hello" />
```

displays a text field populated with *hello*.

Basically all the MVC frameworks allow doing that quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use RequestDispacter object and navigate it to first servlet or jsp page with that error